# Algorithm Design: Stone Merging Game with Scoring

Tags: algorithm

You are given an array of stones with size n+1 where the initial weight of each stone is 1.
You are playing a game with the stones. In each round j starting from 0, select any two adjacent stones and merge them. If the chosen stones have weights x and y, then the resulting stone will have a weight x+y. During this round, you pay a cost x*y*v[j], where v[j] is a non-increasing sequence in j that is provided to you at the start of the game.

By the end of the nth round, you should be left with a single stone weighing n+1. Your goal is to minimize the total cost across all rounds. Design a polynomial-time algorithm to solve this problem.

Examples:

Input: n=5, v=[4,3,2,0,0]
Output: 9

Explanation:  [1 1 1 1 1 1]->[2 1 1 1 1]->[2 2 1 1]->[2 2 2]->[4 2]->[6] The cost is 1*1*4+1*1*3+1*1*2=9

Input: n=5, v=[4,3,1,1,0]
Output: 11

Explanation:  [1 1 1 1 1 1]->[2 1 1 1 1]->[2 1 2 1]->[3 2 1]->[3 3]->[6] The cost is 1*1*4+1*1*3+2*1*1+2*1*1=11

Input: n=5, v=[4,2,2,1,0]
Output: 12

We tried greedy but it was not optimal. We also hoped to use dynamic programming but did not find a polynomial algorithm.

Comment: Your example output doesn't seem to line up with your explanation.  Eg in first example, the output is expected to be 9, your example yields 6. in second example, expected output is 11, your explanation yields 6?  Please explain

Comment: @itprorh66 It does line up. See the edits that explain the example.

Comment: It would se4em to me that the cost of such combinations is always going to be the sum of the values in the v array.

Comment: any constraints on N, or v[j]? something like 1 <= N <= 1000;  0 <= v[j] <= 1000?

Comment: @JamieNguyen The problem does not have such constraints, but it is okay to add such an upper bound if the algorithm needs some upper bound on N or v[j].